# Returning first object in array of objects (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm having trouble with this function. I'm supposed to return the first element of an array, which I'm able to do with arrays of numbers or a string.

```
function firstElement(array) {
  if (array.length === 0) {
    return undefined;
  }
  if (array instanceof Array || typeof(array) === "string") {
    return array[0];
  }
}
firstElement([1, 2, 3]); // 1
firstElement([{ name: “Joseph” }, { name: “Ashley” }, { name: “Brandon” }]); // {name: “Joseph”}
```

However, when it comes to an array of objects, I'm not quite sure how I'm supposed to return the whole object `({name: "Joseph"})`. At first, I tried doing it the same way I would return the first number in a number array, but I was thrown a `SyntaxError`. It seemed as simple as that but I'm just completely stuck now. I want it to be able to work for any `{key: value}` object and not just specifically names.

Can anyone see where I am wrong?

Comment: Looking at what the OP is doing with the type checking, the `length` check should not take place before the type check. Looking additionally at the possible return values, the implementation of `firstElement` could be much simplified based on the usage of `Array.from` and making sure that the passed argument is neither a `null` nor an `undefined` value ...  `function firstElement(value) { return Array.from(value != null ? value : [])[0]; }` ... or in another variant something like ... `const firstElement = value => Array.from(value ?? [])[0];`

Answer (score 2):

According to your object value, it should be `string` but you have used the wrong `double quotes`. It should be `" "` not `“ ”`.

You can also use `single quote` i.e `' '`.Both are acceptable.

Everything else is working fine.

```js
function firstElement(array) {
  if (array.length === 0) {
    return undefined;
  }
  if (array instanceof Array || typeof array === "string") {
    return array[0];
  }
}
const element1 = firstElement([1, 2, 3]); // 1
const element2 = firstElement([{ name: "Joseph" }, { name: "Ashley" }, { name: "Brandon" }]);

console.log( element1 );
console.log( element2 );
```

Comment: Oh, wow. I didn't even realize that the quotes were different. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The object inside your array is incorrect, it should be a string that's why you are getting this issue.
Just change “ to " in the object and your code will work as expected.

Try with the below array once.
[{ name : "Joseph" }, { name: "Ashley" }, { name: "Brandon" }]

```js
function firstElement(array) {
      if (array.length === 0) {
        return undefined;
      }
      if (array instanceof Array || typeof array === "string") {
        return array[0];
      }
    }
   
    const first = firstElement([{ name: "Joseph" }, { name: "Ashley" }, { name: "Brandon" }]);
    console.log("first :", first);
```